# PHP sending empty Form values to Server

Tags: php, html, mysql, php-5.6

This server acknowledges the PHP connection, but the values entered in the form do not get stored just empty table rows.

The PHP code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</h2>

<?php


  $name = $_POST'firstname';
  $last_name =$_POST'lastname';
  $when_it_happened = $_POST'whenithappened';
  $how_long = $_POST'howlong';
  $how_many = $_POST'howmany';
  $alien_description = $_POST'aliendescription';
  $what_they_did = $_POST'whattheydid';
  $fang_spotted = $_POST'fangspotted';
  $email = $_POST'email';
  $other = $_POST'other';

  $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Password', 'aliendatabase')
    or die('Error Connecting to MySQL server');

  $query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name, last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, " .
    "how_many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email) " .
    "VALUES ('$first_name, '$last_name', '$when_it_happened', '$how_long', '$how_many', " .
    "'$alien_description', '$what_they_did', '$fang_spotted', '$other', '$email')";

  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error Querying Database');

  mysqli_close($dbc); 

  echo 'Thanks for submitting the form.<br />';
  echo 'You were abducted ' . $when_it_happened;
  echo ' and were gone for ' . $how_long . '<br />';
  echo 'Number of aliens: ' . $how_many . '<br />';
  echo 'Describe them: ' . $alien_description . '<br />';
  echo 'The aliens did this: ' . $what_they_did . '<br />';
  echo 'Was Fang there? ' . $fang_spotted . '<br />';
  echo 'Other comments: ' . $other . '<br />';
  echo 'Your email address is ' . $email;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the Form/HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</h2>

  <p>Share your story of alien abduction:</p>
  <form method="post" action="report.php">
    <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
    <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />
    <label for="email">What is your email address?</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
    <label for="whenithappened">When did it happen?</label>
    <input type="text" id="whenithappened" name="whenithappened" /><br />
    <label for="howlong">How long were you gone?</label>
    <input type="text" id="howlong" name="howlong" /><br />
    <label for="howmany">How many did you see?</label>
    <input type="text" id="howmany" name="howmany" /><br />
    <label for="aliendescription">Describe them:</label>
    <input type="text" id="aliendescription" name="aliendescription" size="32" /><br />
    <label for="whattheydid">What did they do to you?</label>
    <input type="text" id="whattheydid" name="whattheydid" size="32" /><br />
    <label for="fangspotted">Have you seen my dog Fang?</label>
    Yes <input id="fangspotted" name="fangspotted" type="radio" value="yes" />
    No <input id="fangspotted" name="fangspotted" type="radio" value="no" /><br />
    <img src="fang.jpg" width="100" height="175"
      alt="My abducted dog Fang." /><br />
    <label for="other">Anything else you want to add?</label>
    <textarea id="other" name="other"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Report Abduction" name="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is straight from a book. php v5.6.22 and latest Apache and MySQL. 
Can anyone tell me what might be wrong or what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Your PHP can't possibly be running, it has dozens of syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this => `$_POST'firstname';` and all the other POST arrays?

They are missing brackets `[]` for them.

So change that to `$_POST['firstname'];` and do the same for all the others also.

Error reporting would have helped you here, as would reading the manual on forms.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Plus, you should use a conditional `!empty()` against all your POST arrays going in your database.

This could trigger errors if any of those are left empty, should your database not accept NULL values.

You also have a missing quote for `('$first_name,` and concatenates in your query.

This needed to be rewritten as such:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name, last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, 
    how_many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email) 
    VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$when_it_happened', '$how_long', '$how_many', 
    '$alien_description', '$what_they_did', '$fang_spotted', '$other', '$email')";
```

---

Footnotes:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Error reporting doesn't help when there are syntax errors, since nothing in the script will run.

Comment: @Barmar Have I missed something?

Comment: @Barmar Ok, I spotted more now. Lordie, I think I'll have to rewrite that whole line.

Comment: `$_POST'firstname'` is a syntax error, so the script won't run, so it can't execute `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: @Barmar Oh interesting, I didn't know that till now. One never ceases to learn something, which is the beauty of what I get to learn from you and other Stack members. Thanks

Comment: Thank you missing the brackets, did that but still not working

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bd8y1m here, the filled in blocked is me sending without form.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bd8zri this is the result, i dont think i need error handler just to send data to a server, simple data

Comment: @MrA you don't seem to be running as PHP here. That output shot you gave me, shows variables rather than being parsed. How are you running this as, `file:///file.xxx` or as `http://localhost/file.php`? Two different animals here.

Comment: the files suppose to be in the apache folder?

Comment: @MrA depending on your webserver/php/apache installation and is beyond the scope of the question asked. You will need to consult the documentation for it and then access that file as `http://localhost/file.xxx`.

Comment: It actually worked now, my fault. Thank you so helpful. i didn't have the directory in the root folder of Apache. silly mistakes cause me days of trouble

Comment: @MrA No worries. I'm glad to hear that everything worked out, *cheers!*